# can fourier transform be used in circuit design?

Tags: circuit-design, fourier

If I formulize the input voltage that I am planning to give to a circuit and if I formulize relative output voltage that I expect to see with respect to input voltage, I can take their fourier transform and divide them to find fourier transform of impulse response of the circuit which is LTI if it involves linear or linearized elements I assume. Then I will find reverse fourier transform of fourier transform of impulse response to find impulse response in time domain. By using it,somehow, I want to relate the input voltage to output voltage in a block diagram. Then I will replace those blocks with relative circuit blocks. Ex: if there is a block that integrates input voltage to it, I will replace it with integrator op amp. Is this possible to do this? I would be happy if you correct flaws in my strategy. I searched web/youtube/my text books but there is no such attempt I came across

Comment: Why wouldn't it be possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What kind of hardware implements Fourier transform?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/425008/what-kind-of-hardware-implements-fourier-transform)

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear. It sounds kind of like you are asking whether Fourier analysis works in the real world. It does. For example in filter design components are selected based on pole and zero location.